# When does the sum of squares/cubes of polynomials over finite field have less than maximum degree?

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, polynomials, finite-fields

Given polynomials $p_1(x), p_2(x), \dots p_m(x) \in \mathbb{F}_p[x]/\langle x^p-x\rangle$ where $p$ is a prime, when does $\sum_{i=1}^m p^2_i(x)$ have degree $< p-1$? What about $\sum_{i=1}^m p^3_i(x)$?

I ask this question in the context of coding theory. The polynomials here define a codeword. I want the codewords to have the property $\sum_{x \in \mathbb{F}_p} \sum_{i=1}^m p_i(x) =0$, $\sum_{x \in \mathbb{F}_p} \sum_{i=1}^m p^2_i(x) =0$ and $\sum_{x \in \mathbb{F}_p} \sum_{i=1}^m p^3_i(x) =0$. The first one is simple enough: the sum of the $x^{p-1}$ coefficients have to be 0 (mod p). Are there any such results for the other $2$ terms?